# Persistent python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Is there a way to make a subprocess call in python "persistent"? I'm calling a program that takes a while to load multiple times. So it would be great if I could just leave that program open and communicate with it without killing it.

The cartoon version of my python script looks like this:

```
for text in textcollection:
    myprocess = subprocess.Popen(["myexecutable"],
                stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = None)
    myoutputtext, err = myprocess.communicate(input=text)
```

I need to process each text separately, so joining it all into one large text file and processing it once is not an option.

Preferably, if there's an option like this

```
myprocess = subprocess.Popen(["myexecutable"],
            stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr = None)    for text in textcollection:
for text in textcollection:
    myoutputtext, err = myprocess.communicate(input=text)
```

where I can leave the process open, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `myprocess.stdin.write()` and `myprocess.stdout.read()` to communicate with your subprocess, you just need to be careful to make sure you handle buffering correctly to prevent your calls from blocking.

If the output from your subprocess is well-defined, you should be able to reliably communicate with it using line-buffering and `myprocess.stdout.readline()`.

Here is an example:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], bufsize=1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write('hello world\n')
>>> p.stdout.readline()
'hello world\n'
>>> p.stdout.readline()        # THIS CALL WILL BLOCK
```

An alternative to this method for Unix is to put the file handle in non-blocking mode, which will allow you to call functions like `myprocess.stdout.read()` and have it return data if any is available, or raise an `IOError` if there isn't any data:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> import fcntl, os
>>> fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
0
>>> p.stdout.read()         # raises an exception instead of blocking
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This would allow you to do something like this:

```
fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
for text in textcollection:
    myprocess.stdin.write(text + '\n')
    while True:
        myoutputtext = ''
        try:
            myoutputtext += myprocess.stdout.read()
        except IOError:
            pass
        if validate_output(myoutputtext):
            break
        time.sleep(.1)    # short sleep before attempting another read
```

In this example, `validate_output()` is a function you would need to write that returns `True` if the data you have received so far is all of output that you expect to get.

Comment: Thanks! I like your solution the best since it doesn't require a third party download. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. After trying out a few things, I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the java program I'm calling rather than your solution, so your solution is good.

Comment: This was by mistake. My upvote is inactive until anything will be edited, but I do not see anything to improve or not hurt. Perfect answer.

Comment: @hynekcer, no problem, thanks for the response :)  Just made a minor edit.

Comment: gives me error `    myprocess.stdout.read()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    data = self.buffer + input
TypeError: can't concat NoneType to bytes
`

Answer (score 5):

It is the call to `communicate()` that is killing your subprocess. According to the [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) the `communicate()` method will:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

What you want to do is interact directly with the `POpen` object's `stdin` and `stdout` properties directly to communicate with the subprocess. However, the documentation advises against this saying:

> Warning: Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

So you either need to implement your own workarounds for potential deadlocks, or hope that someone has written an [asynchronous subprocess module](http://code.google.com/p/subprocdev/source/browse/subprocess.py) for you.

**Edit:** Here's a quick'n'dirty example of how the asynchronous subprocess module could be used:

```
import asyncsubprocess

textcollection = ['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to be', 'that is the', 'question']

myprocess = asyncsubprocess.Popen(["cat"],
     stdin = asyncsubprocess.PIPE,
     stdout = asyncsubprocess.PIPE,
     stderr = None)

for text in textcollection:
    bytes_sent, myoutput, err = myprocess.listen(text)
    print text, bytes_sent, myoutput, err
```

When I run this, it prints:

```
to 2 to 
be 2 be 
or 2 or 
not 3 not 
to be 5 to be 
that is the 11 that is the 
question 8 question
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
myprocess.stdin.write(text)
```

you could create a list of Popens and then call communicate on each element in another loop.
something like this

```
processes=[]
for text in textcollection:
    myprocess = subprocess.Popen(["myexecutable"],
                stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = None)
    myprocess.stdin.write(text)
    processes.append(myprocess)

for proc in processes:
    myoutput, err=proc.communicate()
    #do something with the output here
```

this way it won't have to wait until after all the Popens have started

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me because it's a java program that eats up about 3G of memory on each run. This is why it takes so long to load. I can't have 5000 instances of a 3G process.

Comment: I think I understand.  After it gets the input text, it outputs something and then exits? or does it wait for you to enter something else

Answer (score -4):

```
if os.name == 'nt':
 startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
 startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
 subprocess.call(os.popen(tempFileName), shell=True)
 os.remove(tempFileName)
```

Comment: You might want to have some explanation of your answer at least.  With that a non-cross-platform answer may be better accepted...