# Reading carriage return delimited output from a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to read output, line by line, of a program that uses carriage returns (`\r`) to make its output. The program runs for a long time, so I need to read the output as the program runs. I know how to do this when each item of output appears on a new line (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980050/persistent-python-subprocess)), but I can't seem to get it to work with carriage returns.

Here is the code I used to try and get it to work (run on a linux system)

```
import subprocess

command = ["printf", "".join(["Return count: " + str(x) + "\\r" for x in range(10)]) + "\n"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
buf = bytearray()
out = proc.stdout
while True:
    c = out.read()
    if c == b"":
        break
    if c == "\r":
        print(buf)
        buf = bytearray()
    else:
        buf += c

print("Done")
```

However the code simply exits immediately, printing `Done`.

I want the code to print:

```
Return code: 1
Return code: 2
Return code: 3
```

etc. What do I need to modify to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get byte by byte you need to pass a number of bytes to get to [`read` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read):

```
c = out.read(1)
```

Otherwise, it will read whole content.

Comment: To read the output line-by-line, wouldn't one want to use `for line in out:`?

Comment: @martineau Because it's delimited by carriage returns not newlines. You know how some terminal programs (like apt-get's progress bar) update the line in place. I'm dealing with a program that does that.