# How can I call a command using Python, capturing stderr and stdout, without waiting for stderr/stdout to be closed?

Tags: python, subprocess

Right now I have some code that uses [`Popen.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) from subprocess (setting `stdin=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE`) to run a command and capture both stderr and stdout.

The problem is that `communicate()` not only waits for the command to exit, it waits for stdout and stderr to be closed. The command I'm running spawns a child process which keeps stderr open, so even though the command is finished running (and shows as "defunct" in ps) `communicate()` is still hung.

I want to only wait for the command to finish without waiting on stderr/stdout. But I still want to capture any stderr/stdout output given while the command was running. [The documentation for `wait()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) is accompanied by a red box with a disclaimer:

> This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

Obviously, I also want to avoid deadlocks.

What is the right way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Maybe you'll get interesting information from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140189/subprocess-popen-stdout-reading-stdout-in-real-time-again or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411966/printing-stdout-in-realtime-from-a-subprocess-that-requires-stdin

Comment: Could spawn separate threads to read the process's `stdout` and `stderr` so that you can call `wait()` without worrying about buffers filling up. Complicated part is if you want to stop reading `stderr`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076542/how-can-i-read-all-availably-data-from-subprocess-popen-stdout-non-blocking/

Comment: @DanGetz thanks, I think that will work. Will report back if I get a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

*"shows as "defunct" in ps"* implies that you might be on a system where `select` or `fcntl` would work i.e., you can read stdout/stderr without blocking easily.

Example: A starts B (`cmd`, the child), B starts C (grandchild), A reads output until B exits or EOF:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from select import select
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=0)
read_set = [p.stdout, p.stderr]
pipename = {p.stdout: "stdout", p.stderr: "stderr"}
timeout = 0.5 # ugly but it works
while read_set and p.poll() is None: # while subprocess is running or until EOF
    for pipe in select(read_set, [], [], timeout)[0]:
        data = os.read(pipe.fileno(), 1<<30)
        if data:
            print("got from %s: %r" % (pipename[pipe], data))
        else: # EOF
            pipe.close()
            read_set.remove(pipe)
print("exit code %s" % (p.wait(),))

# child exited, wait for grandchild to print
for pipe in read_set:
    print("read the rest of %s: %r" % (pipename[pipe], pipe.read()))
    pipe.close()
```

where `cmd`:

```
import sys
from textwrap import dedent

cmd = [sys.executable, '-u', '-c', dedent("""
    # inception style
    import os
    import sys
    from subprocess import Popen
    from textwrap import dedent

    Popen([sys.executable, '-u', '-c', dedent('''
        import os
        import sys
        import time

        time.sleep(60)
        print("grandchild %d done" % os.getpid())
        sys.stderr.write("grandchild stderr")
        sys.exit(20)
    ''')]) # stdout/stderr are not redirected

    print('child %d done' % os.getpid())
    sys.stderr.write('child stderr')
    sys.exit(19)
""")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a simple example. And all I've got so far is capturing of the std.err I've created two files. The contents of the first is (example1.py):

```
import time
import sys

for i in xrange(1000):
    print >>sys.stderr, "hello", i
    time.sleep(1)
```

The contents of the second one(example2.py):

```
import subprocess

cmd = "python example1.py"

print subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

And that I've just called the example2.py script:

python example2.py
And I've realtime output ( I assume it is true:) ):

```
hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
hello 4
hello 5
hello 6
```

Still, I have no idea, how to deal with standard output, but if I manage it, I will post the answer here